# How to insert a list of data in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a list of integers and list names and I inserted this information in mongodb via console using following code

```
db.collection.insert({"_id":"integers","data":[1,2,3,4,5]})
db.collection.insert({"_id":"names","data":["A","B","C","D"]})
```

the query `db.collection.find().pretty` gave the following result

```
{ "_id" : "ArrayList", "data" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
{
    "_id" : "Names",
    "data" : [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ]
}
```

How to do it in java?

Comment: Plenty of [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/) out there to get you started.

Comment: The _ids are not matching. names become "Names", integers became "ArrayList". Please ensure that question is consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the list as second arg for [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html)

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("_id", "ArrayList").append("data", list);

    coll.insert(doc);
```

Comment: `BasicDBObject` uses the default `_id` i.e. `ObjectId` but how to specify own `_id`. Please see the question

Comment: Answer updated, In your case, you have to explicitly put the "_id"